# What is the default RBAC scope used when assigning a role in Azure with the CLI?

Tags: azure, entra-id, azure-cli

This is the documentation for the `az role assignment create` command: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-role-assignment-create

`--score` is an optional parameter. This is what the documentation says about it:

> Scope at which the role assignment or definition applies to, e.g., /subscriptions/0b1f6471-1bf0-4dda-aec3-111122223333, /subscriptions/0b1f6471-1bf0-4dda-aec3-111122223333/resourceGroups/myGroup, or /subscriptions/0b1f6471-1bf0-4dda-aec3-111122223333/resourceGroups/myGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/myVM.

As you can see, it doesn't say what the default value for this parameter is. I can't find it anywhere, so I found myself forced to ask here.

Comment: I can't select my own answer as the correct one because I have to wait 2 days, but that's the correct answer anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-cli#step-4-assign-role

Apparently, when the `--scope` parameter is not provided its value depends on whether the `--resource-group` parameter is provided or not. If you provide that parameter, then it's like if you specified the resource group scope. Else, the subscription scope is assumed.